# How to use a Postgresql window function to filter between times that beyond midnight?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, window-functions

I would like to apply window function between times that beyond midnight.
The following is a part of example data of per-minute values one stock.
Actually it does exists more longer that the example.

Data type of datetime is timestamptz and others are int.

I want to query diff of first price and last price between 22:30-04:21 for each day.

How I can do it?

I want to do seems like following but it does not work.

```
select distinct datetime::date, first_value(open) over w as first, last_value(close) over w as last 
from price_table window w as 
(partition by datetime::time range between 22:30 and 04:21);
```

price_table:

```
datetime    open    high    low     close   volume // type of datetime is timestamptz others are int.
...
 
// there is a more older value (several years actually) 

2023/01/03  23:50   25830   25840   25830   25830   1139
2023/01/03  23:51   25835   25835   25820   25825   786
2023/01/03  23:52   25825   25845   25825   25835   1196
2023/01/03  23:53   25840   25840   25825   25825   874
2023/01/03  23:54   25825   25835   25820   25825   680
2023/01/03  23:55   25820   25825   25810   25815   1237
2023/01/03  23:56   25810   25815   25805   25810   1163
2023/01/03  23:57   25810   25835   25810   25815   1753
2023/01/03  23:58   25810   25840   25810   25830   823
2023/01/03  23:59   25835   25845   25830   25845   1008
2023/01/03  0:00    25845   25855   25840   25850   1235
2023/01/03  0:01    25850   25850   25845   25845   439
2023/01/03  0:02    25845   25850   25835   25840   1146
2023/01/03  0:03    25840   25855   25840   25845   668
...
```

---

Expected Result table: (`diff` is a result of subtraction of last value in the period (close) and first value in the period(close).)

```
date          open     close    diff
2023/01/03    25810    25840    30
2023/01/04    25830    25820    20
```

Comment: Please give an example of the expected output. Also, make sure that the example of input data has values such that it is clear which values contributed to the output.

Comment: Please update the question so that the values in _price_table_ include the corresponding values for the expected output. As it is now, the expected results seem to be unrelated to the input values.

Answer (score 1):

The following query produces the results described in the original question:

```
WITH daily_prices AS (
  SELECT
      DATE_TRUNC('day', datetime + INTERVAL 'PT1H30M')::date AS date,
      (ARRAY_AGG(open ORDER BY datetime))[1] AS open,
      (ARRAY_AGG(close ORDER BY datetime DESC))[1] AS close
    FROM
      price_table
    WHERE
         datetime::time >= '21:30'
      OR datetime::time <= '04:21'
    GROUP BY
      date)
SELECT date, open, close, close - open as diff
  FROM daily_prices
  ORDER BY date;
```

The query uses a common table expression (CTE) to reduce redundant calculations. Although not a major issue in this case, repeated code can be a maintenance issue when the calculations are more complex or produce values that are needed in multiple places. Even for a query as simple as this one, repeating calculations would make the code more difficult to understand and increase opportunities to introduce defects.

The query starts by determining the effective date of each price record by adding an offset and then keeping the date portion of the resulting value. Rows are filtered by the unadjusted time and grouped by *price_date* regardless of whether a record's time occurs before or after midnight.

Since `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` are window functions but not aggregate functions, they can't reference non-grouped values; however, the desired results can be obtained by collecting values into sorted arrays and taking the first element. To get the last value, the array is sorted in descending order so that it isn't necessary to know how many elements are in the array.

The intuition to employ `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` was reasonable, but leads to a sligtly verbose solution. Contrast the above query with the following:

```
WITH parms AS (
  SELECT INTERVAL 'PT1H30M' as time_shift),
daily_prices AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    (datetime + parms.time_shift)::date AS date,
    FIRST_VALUE(open) OVER (PARTITION by (datetime + parms.time_shift)::date
                            ORDER BY datetime) AS open,
    LAST_VALUE(close) OVER (PARTITION by (datetime + parms.time_shift)::date
                             ORDER BY datetime
                             ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS close
    FROM
      parms CROSS JOIN price_table
    WHERE
         datetime::time >= '22:30'
      OR datetime::time <= '04:21')
SELECT date, open, close, close - open as diff
  FROM daily_prices
  ORDER BY date;
```

The function names `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` reflect the operation to be performed and are therefore more intuitive than the use of `ARRAY_AGG` in the first query; however, that advantage is offset by the amount of additional code required. Some of the extra code can be eliminated; e.g., the window frame definition can be omitted if `FIRST_VALUE` is used instead of `LAST_VALUE` and the order is changed to `datetime DESC`. While doing so reduces the amount of code, it also dispenses with the intuitive advantage of `LAST_VALUE` over `ARRAY_AGG`. A bigger issue is the need to repeat the partitioning expression. It's a minor annoyance in such a brief query, but becomes a more significant concern as the number of repetitions increases.

Avoid using SQL keywords as column names. `CLOSE`, `DATE`, and `OPEN` are keywords in PostgreSQL and SQL and are also reserved in SQL. I would also avoid using *datetime* as a column name, it's not descriptive and is used as a type or function name in some SQL implementations; e.g., SQLite, MySQL, and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to solve the different days is to subtract (or add) a certain amount of time to each date so that the values around midnight will be considered for the same date. For example like this:

```sql
select distinct (datetime - INTERVAL '5 hour')::date,
first_value(open) over (partition by (datetime - INTERVAL '5 hour')::date order by datetime) as open,
last_value(close) over (partition by (datetime - INTERVAL '5 hour')::date order by datetime RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as close,
last_value(close) over (partition by (datetime - INTERVAL '5 hour')::date order by datetime RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) - first_value(open) over (partition by (datetime - INTERVAL '5 hour')::date order by datetime) as diff
from price_table
where datetime::time between '22:30' and '23:59' or datetime::time between '00:00' and '04:21';
```

Here the values around midnight are considered for the day before midnight, e.g. "2023/01/04  0:03" is considered for 2023/01/03. If you would like to consider them for the day after midnight instead, you have to change `- INTERVAL '5 hour'` to `+ INTERVAL '2 hour'`.

Comment: Please don't post answers that haven't been tested. This code does not work due to several issues:  the `BETWEEN` operator will never evaluate to true because the lower value is greater than the upper; partitions are sorted by `datetime::time` instead of `datetime`, and the `LAST_VALUE` expressions don't have window specifications (window functions default to `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING TO CURRENT ROW`). The difference should also be last close - first open.

Comment: Good catches, I've fixed my answer based on them. Testing this would require a lot of work since the asker didn't include a proper example dataset (e.g. on dbfiddle). The main idea from my answer is the subtraction/addition of a specific amount of time, I've also clarified that now.